# V is a subspace of R³. What are the possible dimensions to V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to solve this problem. But when I search I find different situations.

My question is

*V is a subspace of R³. What are the possible dimensions to V?*

Thank you guys.

Comment: Lets think about it... Can you think of a zero dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?  Can you think of a one dimensional subspace?  A two dimensional?  Three dimensional?  Four dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?  Any other number larger than four?  Can vector spaces have a number of dimensions that aren't a natural number or infinity according to the definitions you have been given so far (*which likely involve the number of basis elements*)?

Comment: Looks to me anywhere between 0 and 3 (inclusive)..

Comment: I think that now I am understanding. Thanks you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V$ can have dimension $0,1,2$ or $3$.
Take for instance the origin, for the $0$-dimensional space.  You could use the spaces spanned by any $1,2$ or $3$ linearly independent vectors, as examples.  Well, in the case of dimension $1$, just the span of a nonzero vector...

As to the possibility of fractional dimension, i found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1513361).

Maybe there are more possibilities...

Comment: I think that now I am understanding. Thanks you!!!

Comment: You're very welcome.